# SQL Servers: Linked-servers without linking servers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, linked-server

Both my local (and remote) SQL SERVER 2005 administrators claim that "allowing linked-servers is a security issue" and forbid their use here.  (Huh?)

Anyway, is there a way to do something similar WITHOUT linked-servers?

```
SELECT *
FROM LOCAL_SERVER.MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable AS t1
INNER JOIN REMOTE_SERVER.MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable AS t2
ON t1.MyField = t2.MyField
```

Comment: Ask your administrators to replicate or mirror the DB to your local server?

Comment: <Rant>If they're going to forbid something, they should be prepared to recommend and support alternatives.</Rant>

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli, boy are you right there. I'd make them come up with the alternative and if they didn't I'd escalate the problem.

Answer (score 8):

You could use [OPENROWSET](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx), which'll require the connection info, username & password...

While I understand that the administrator believes that having an always-on connection to their data is risky, that's why you lock down the account. OPENROWSET means including the connection info in plain text.

Answer (score 4):

yes you can use [OPENDATASOURCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179856.aspx) but ad-hoc queries have to be enabled

Opendatasource: Provides ad hoc connection information as part of a four-part object name without using a linked server name.

Comment: +1: I'm trying to find the difference between OPENDATASOURCE & OPENROWSET - very little, just OPENROWSET supports bulk operations...

Comment: Yes OPENROWSET added bulk for XML in 2005 IIRC